# Can I turn the input range into an audio player? and How do I link the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, input, audio-player

I have been trying to figure out if I can turn the input slider into an audio player. It's the one with the `(class = "progress-bar")`.
This is the basic design.

I am not sure if it is possible, but I would to be pointed in the right direction to complete this music player.

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="Song-Photo">
    <img src="https://th.bing.com/th?id=OIF.%2fA7TZqecnjxCdpKO6nnZ3w&pid=ImgDet&rs=1" alt="Kung-Fu Kenny">
  </div>
  <div class="Music-Player">
    <div class="Song-Title">Heart Part V</div>
    <span id="Audio-Player">
      <div class="current-time"> Current-Time </div>
      <input id="Audio-Player" class="progress-bar" min="0" max="0" type="range">
      <div class="duration">Duration</div>
      <button class="mute">Mute</button>
      <input id="Audio-Player" class="volume" type="range" min="0" max="100">
    </span>
    <div id="button-functions" class="Audio-Playback">
      <button id="button-functions" class="rewind">Rewind</button>
      <button id="button-functions" class="play-pause">Play</button>
      <button id="button-functions" class="fast-forward">Fast-Forward</button>
      <button id="button-functions" class="random-shuffle-repeat">Shuffle/Repeat</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Artist">Kendrick Lamar</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Post JavaScript and HTML as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by turning into an audio player?

An audio player is like this:

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
    <audio
        controls
        src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
</figure>
```

If you want to turn the input slider into an audio player, replace with the above code I guess.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out. Yeah, I would like to load mp3s and have it play. Something like a simple streaming music player.

Comment: @DeshawnReid Good luck, I guess the above code will work for you. After testing, don't forget to click the grey check mark next to my answer. Thanks!